# PHP ldap_connect() problems

Tags: php, apache, ldapconnection

I am trying to get ldap_connect to work properly. It will work fine via CLI, but not when I open my php file via browser.

Here is what I believe are the relevant details:

- Error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in F:\Websites\ldap.php on line 4
- OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
- PHP Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP
- libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll have been added to both C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin and C:\Windows\System32. They were copied from C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP.

Lines added to httpd.conf:

- LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
- AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
- PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP"

Things changed in php.ini:

- extension_dir = "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/ext"   (path set)
- extension=php_ldap.dll   (uncommented this line)

I'm pulling my hair out, so I am more than happy to try anything people suggest.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server to reload the php.ini?  Also is your apache server using the same php as the the cli?

Comment: I have restarted the server. Is there a way to check? I only have one install of PHP on here.

Comment: It appears as though when I run php_info in a file via CLI (and output that to a file), it's different than when I pull it up in a browser.

Comment: I don't have a clue then.  You running XAMPP?

Comment: I am not. This is a clean install of PHP and Apache on a fresh load of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP installation uses two different ini files - one when running from the command line, and a different one when running through Apache. This is evidenced by the fact that it works from the CLI, but not in a browser.

You can find the paths to the two files using `phpinfo()` (in a browser) and by passing the `-i` flag to `php` from the command line. Near the top of both sets of output you will find the path to the ini file in use, and I would be mighty surprised if they were identical. From the command line you can get more detailed information by passing the `--ini` flag.

The fact that you are getting `Call to undefined function ldap_connect()` can *only* mean that the LDAP extension was not loaded, and this can only be true through Apache but not through the CLI if they use two different ini files.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I posted this late in the day at work and forgot to check it when I got home.

Output from running php via cli with the -i flag shows this as the path: Loaded Configuration File => C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini

php_info() shows this as the path: Loaded Configuration File C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini

Am I crazy or are those the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly now. The problem was with adding my PHP directory to the PATH environment variable. I'm not 100% sure why it fixed the problem, but that was what ended up doing it. Thanks for the help, guys!